# Detect phone shake - NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

I need to detect phone shake for a mobile app I am developing using NativeScript, but I can't find a "detect shake" plug in for it.

I was able to download the [accelerometer plug in](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-accelerometer) but then I am not sure what to do. I found some instructions [here](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=529&recipeFrom=ViewTOC) that give me some idea, but I still can't figure it out.

Comment: Basically you need the logic showcased in the `isAccelerationChanged()` method from the example. Calculate the difference of X, Y, and Z to find delta and compare it with the threshold.

Comment: Right, but how do I set the threshold? The example says: private final float shakeThreshold = 1.5f; what the hell is 1.5f?

Comment: It's just a constant number, 1.5f is simply 1.5 - floating point number.

Comment: Thanks. What is the f though? I can't use it in JavaScript or Typescript

Comment: As I mentioned already, it's just a notation used in Java to keep the variable as float instead of double which is default. With JavaScript you could say just 1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a shake detector demo in the nativescript-accelerometer plugin: https://github.com/vakrilov/native-script-accelerometer/blob/master/demo/app/home/shake-detector.ts

I have also prepared a blog-post on the matter which is going to be live in https://www.nativescript.org/blog soon, but you can check-out the draft here: https://hackmd.io/@dIRRNt8TT36EHJdTwYFzmQ/rymDcLYqB